# Continuity of a sum of a series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, continuity

Let $y_n(x)=x^2+\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}+\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}+...+\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^{n-1}}$ and $y(x)=\lim _\limits{n \to \infty}y_n(x)$. Hence, discuss the continuity of $y_n(x) (n = 1,2,3,...,n)$ and $y(x)$ at $x=0$

Now, here's my approach. First, I wrote $y_n(x)$ as the sum of a geometric series as $$y_n(x)= \frac{x^2\bigg(1-\bigg(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\bigg)^n \bigg)}{1-\bigg(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\bigg)}$$
$$\implies y_n(x) = \frac{x^2(1+x^2)\bigg(1-\bigg(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\bigg)^n\bigg)}{x^2}$$

Now, since I am analyzing the continuity of the function at $x = 0$, if I'm not wrong, I can't divide by $x^2$ in the numerator and denominator here. So, I get $y_n(0) =$ not defined. On the other hand, $$\lim _\limits{x \to 0}y_n(x) = 0$$

So I get that $y_n(x)$ is discontinuous at $x = 0$
Now, since $y(x)$ is the limit of the sum of the series when $n \to \infty$, $$y(x)=\frac{x^2}{1-\bigg(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\bigg)}$$ $$\implies y(x) = \frac{x^2(x^2+1)}{x^2}$$

Now, $y(x)$ also seems to be undefined at $x=0$ and thus it is also discontinuous at $x=0$

Thus my answer comes to be that both $y_n(x)$ and $y(x)$ are discontinuous at $x=0$

But the book states the answer as "$y_n(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$ for all $n$ and $y(x)$ is discontinuous at $x=0$".
How is $y_n(x)$ continuous here??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use the formula for  a geometric sum when $x=0$. Directly from the definition we get $y_n(0)=0$ for all $n$ so $y(0)=0$. $y_n$ is continuous because it is a finite sum of continuous functions. $y(x)=1+x^{2}$ for $x \neq 0$ and $y(0)=0$ so $y$ is not continuous at $0$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why can we not use it from the formula for a geometric sum when $x=0$? Is it because a geometric sum is only defined if $|r|<1$ where $r$ is the common difference, and that is not being followed when $x=0$?

Comment: Also, how is $y(0) = 0$?

Comment: @Techie5879 $y(0)=\lim y_n(0)=\lim 0 =0$.

Comment: You cannot have $0$ in the denominator. That is why your formula for the geometric sum cannot be used when $x=0$.  @Techie5879